# I want to print numbers pattern program but it not give me wrong out put

Tags: php

I want to get my output like this

```
1 5 9  13
2 6 10 14
3 7 11 15
4 8 12 16
```

I am trying like this:

```
<?php
for($a=1; $a<=16; $a++)
{
 for($b=$a; $b>=1; $b--)
   {
     echo "$b";
   }
echo "<br>";
}
?>
```

The above code gives me the wrong output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's debug.

You are starting from `1` in your outer loop and in your inner loop, you are going from `$a` till `1` times.

This doesn't comply with your requirements because we have to print an increasing sequence in each row.

You can also notice that every number in a row differs by `4`.

So, logic would be like below:

**Pseudocode:**

```
rows = 4
starting_number = 1
loop from 1 to rows
   number = starting_number 
   loop from 1 to 4 // since each row has 4 numbers
     print number 
     number += 4
   print new_line
   starting_number++
```

**Demo:** https://3v4l.org/9YjIP

Comment: your output is showing like this `1 5 9 13 2 6 10 14 3 7 11 15 4 8 12 16`

Comment: @farhantechno Most likely you are testing in the browser. Use `echo "<br/>";` instead of `echo PHP_EOL;`.